# Comparing and displaying the values in the same table in sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle

I am very new to sqlplus and I have very limited knowledge about the subject, can anyone please help me in this:

I have a table which contains the columns: code, value and date

Here there are 2 types of values in the code column, ex: ABC.1 and DEF.1. Here the DEF.1 has the values for all the dates, but the same is not true for ABC.1, it is missing values for some dates. I'm trying to write a query to extract the data if there is a value in DEF.1 for a particular date and the value is not present for ABC.1 for the same date.

Ex:

```
+------------------------------+
| Code    Value     Date       |
+------------------------------+
| DEF.1    44       22-11-2019 |
+------------------------------+
| ABC.1    23       23-11-2019 |
+------------------------------+
| DEF.1    12       23-11-2019 |
+------------------------------+
| ABC.1    99       24-11-2019 |
+------------------------------+
| DEF.1    23       24-11-2019 |
+------------------------------+
```

Here ABC.1 does not have a value for the date 22-11-2019, so for that date I want to extract the values of DEF.1

Comment: Do you mean to say you want one more row like `ABC.1 , 44 ,22-11-2019` ?

Comment: No, just the value DEF.1, 44, 22-11-2019 needs be displayed. The year ranges from 2017 to 2019

Comment: I need the value to be exported into a csv file to keep a record of what values are present for DEF.1 and not for ABC.1.

Comment: Is there for each day one possible row or is it possible that you have two rows with DEF.1 for the same day? And is it possible that ABC.1 exisits for one date but DEF.1 is missing?
Example:
DEF.1 , 44 ,22-11-2019
DEF.1 , 90 ,22-11-2019

Comment: Yes there are multiple values for the same dates, and the codes DEF.1 is not missing any values for any of the dates.

Comment: @Phoenix What about ABC.1 can there be multiple values with code ABC.1 for the same date? Or will there be 0-1 rows for ABC.1 each day?

Comment: @Mihawk Yes, if there are 4 values for code DEF.1, then there will be 4 values for ABC.1 each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this question using `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.code = 'DEF.1' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.date = t.date and t2.code = 'ABC.1'
                 );
```

With an index on `(date, code)`, I would expect this to have very good performance.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and probably fastest would be analytical `count`:

```
select code, value, date_
  from (
    select code, value, date_, 
           count(case code when 'ABC.1' then 1 end) over (partition by date_) c1,
           count(case code when 'DEF.1' then 1 end) over (partition by date_) c2
      from tbl t)
  where c1 <> c2
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7d6bed84fce6d49c5718274bba2dda8c)</sup>**

You can also use `not exists`, `not in` and grouping, but if you want details anaytic way is shortest. This query shows all rows where `count` is different, so if there are 3 `ABC` and 5 `DEF` you will get 8 rows for that date. It also works if rows are missing, like in your example. `Date` is reserved word so I added underscore.